# Move Uploaded File in PHP is not working

Tags: php, file

move_uploaded_file is not working in PHP.
Below is the code

```
$TempFilePath ='../tmp';
$filename = $custid.$HTTP_POST_FILES['upload']['name'];
if(move_uploaded_file($HTTP_POST_FILES['upload']['tmp_name'], $setTempFilePath .$filename)){
    echo '<br>File Moved <bR>';
    if (file_exists($TempFilePath .$filename)){
        echo '<br> File Exists <br>';
    } else {
        echo '<br> File doesnt Exists <br>';
    }
else {
    echo '<br>File not Moved <bR>';
}
```

Output is :

```
File Moved 

File doesnt Exists
```

Bug: If file moved, then why file doesnt exists.

Comment: `$setTempFilePath .$filename` vs `$TempFilePath .$filename` ?

Comment: Use `$_FILES` and not `$HTTP_POST_FILES`

Comment: Your code seems to be missing a `}` somewhere.

Comment: note that $HTTP_POST_FILES is deprecated. you should NOT be using it in any new code.

Comment: Try  `$TempFilePath ='../tmp/'`

Comment: **Hay fixing the code ERROR BY ERROR as they are reported to you is not the way this site works** It makes quite valid answers look like nonsense

Comment: $_FILES also not working as it is php 4.4.1. I think $HTTP_POST_FILES is valid.

Comment: According to [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.files.php) `$_FILES` is available since 4.1.0

Comment: Yeah... I tried with $_FILES also, its not working.Same output

Comment: If I change target path to '../tmp1/' then its working.

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured it out.
https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=32644 (And you are aware that Apache does an internal 'cwd /' ?)